# jQuery object within array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to write an each function that looks at each list item and then within that item to each span, applying some css to each span uniquely..

When I start to get down into it I get lost and can't really figure out how to correctly get the unique values to each span within each list item..

http://jsfiddle.net/anthonybruno/9sKNZ/2/

Any ideas?

**Edit** - I realize that this seems like a job for class names but I have simplified the type of css I am trying to use for this example only. Later on I'll be passing some more complex css that will rely on other values such as scrollTop and viewportHeight.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What color should `spanOne` be? `pink` or `purple`? Why the array with stuff? I don't get it...I mean if it's css why not set it in a css stylesheet and if you need to change styles use classes with `addClass` `removeClass` `toggleClass`

Comment: The idea is that the first list item, within that the first span has a font-weight of bold, second list item first span should be purple, third list item first span should be pink. I've simplified the css in this demo. The final code will contain other values such as scroll positions.

Comment: Use a css class? This example is odd... There are names like spanOne etc. yet the spans themselves have no names or ids. You could use class selectors to add or remove other CSS classes dynamically. Trying to do it the way shown in your example is bound to be brittle.

Comment: @Bruno Why `spanOne`, `spanTwo` and `spanThree`? Can I change that structure?

Comment: @Vega - Yep. All names can be changed.

Comment: Agree with the comments. Doesn't seem to be the best way to achieve what you want. Classes will work better. In css you can use `nth-child` if you want to grab the 2nd, 3rd span etc...

Comment: Classes will not work as I'll be doing things later on such as adding a padding top which has a px value of say the scrollTop value.

Comment: Then use classes for presentation (colors, backgrounds etc..) and jQuery for layout (padding, margin...). The thing that makes little sense is that array of non-semantically named stuff.

Comment: @Bruno Did you try any of these answers.. Mine is >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/10821929/297641 << Let us know if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it will be better if you change your `items` like following:

```
var items = [
    [
    'font-weight: bold',
     'text-decoration: underline',
     'text-transform: uppercase',
    ],
    [
    'color: purple',
    'color: yellow',
    ], 
    [
    'color: pink'
    ]
  ];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function(liIndex, li) {
        $('span', this).each(function(index, el) {
            var curCSS = items[liIndex][index].split(':');
            $(this).css(curCSS[0], curCSS[1])
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/9sKNZ/4/)**

If you don't want to change the `items` structure then try this:

```
var items = [
    {
    spanOne: 'font-weight: bold',
    spanTwo: 'text-decoration: underline',
    spanThree: 'text-transform: uppercase'},
{
    spanOne: 'color: purple',
    spanTwo: 'color: yellow'},
{
    spanOne: 'color: pink'}
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ref = ['spanOne', 'spanTwo', 'spanThree']; // an array to make reference
    $('li').each(function(liIndex, li) {
        $('span', this).each(function(index, span) {
            var curCSS = items[liIndex][ref[index]].split(':');
            $(this).css(curCSS[0], curCSS[1])
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/9sKNZ/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

IT is easier if you change your items structure.. see below,

```
var items = [['font-weight: bold',
    'text-decoration: underline',
    'text-transform: uppercase'],
    ['color: purple', 'color: yellow'],
    ['color: pink']];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function(liIdx) { // For each list item
        var curCss = items[liIdx];
        $(this).find('span').each(function(idx) {
            var cssStyle = curCss[idx].split(':');
            $(this).css(cssStyle[0], cssStyle[1]);
        }); // Each span should get unique css value            
    });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sKNZ/3/)